# Strapi Send email with SendGrid "Internal Error"

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid, strapi

I'm trying to send an email with SendGrid. However, it doesn't work. I configured SendGrip as

```
Setup->Guide->Integrate->Web API->Node.js and get "myKeyFromSendGrid"
```

I setup the file config/plugins.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({   // ...   email: {     provider: "sendgrid",     providerOptions: {       apiKey: env(         "myKeyFromSendGrid"       ),     },     settings: {       defaultFrom: "test@test.com",       defaultReplyTo: "no-reply@test.com",     },   },   // ... });
```

I started my Strapi server, and configured at Roles & Permissions the Email Send to Public. Then, I went to Postman and create a new POST request "http://localhost:1337/email" with this content:

```
{

  "to": "test@example.com",

  "from": "test@example.com",

  "subject": "Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun",

  "text": "and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js",

  "html": "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>"

}
```

But I keep receiving "Internal Server Error" from Postman, and from Strapi Debug

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Cannot wrap non-Error object
>
> at Function.boomify (C:\Users\GustavoRangel\Documents\Development\sandbox\personal_blog\server\node_modules\boom\lib\index.js:107:14)
>
> at formatBoomPayload (C:\Users\GustavoRangel\Documents\Development\sandbox\personal_blog\server\node_modules\strapi\lib\middlewares\boom\index.js:47:22)
>        at C:\Users\GustavoRangel\Documents\Development\sandbox\personal_blog\server\node_modules\strapi\lib\middlewares\boom\index.js:84:36
>
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Any idea on what am I doing wrong? I am using Strapi v3.0.1